# How to remove #foofoo in the url when using bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, url

I am using `bootstrap`(version:`3.3.7`) to achieve a simple navigation. 
This is my code:

```
   <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="lib/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#SNP">SNP</a> </li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#SSR">SSR</a> </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="SNP" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                Something about SNP.
            </div>
            <div id="SSR" class="tab-pane fade">
                Something about SSR.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

When i first come to this page, Chrome (version: `57.0.2987.110`) shows that The URL is `www.foofoo.org/page1`. It becomes `www.foofoo.org/page1#SNP` or `www.foofoo.org/page1#SSR` while i click the links include in the *ul a* tag. How to make url to be `www.foofoo.org/page1` no matter which link I click (In other words, The URL is always `www.foofoo.org/page1`).

Comment: Why do you care about that anyway?

Comment: @DavidG If i click the SSR link, url is `www.foofoo.org/page1#SSR`. However, the url is still `www.foofoo.org/page#SSR` and its conent go to  SNP content when i refresh the page.  :)

Comment: As far as I understand, you want your URL address to stay the same after clicking the link, but the content on webpage to change? If so, you would probably need jQuery to handle it without refreshing the page.

Comment: @encrypted21 Yes. It is what i want to achieve. Fortunately, DavidG have given a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be able to get the same effect by using the `data-target` attribute instead of `href` in your anchor tags:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" data-target="#SNP">SNP</a> </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" data-target="#SSR">SSR</a> </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="SNP" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        Something about SNP.
    </div>
    <div id="SSR" class="tab-pane fade">
        Something about SSR.
    </div>
</div>
```

This means you won't get a URL change in your address bar. However, I would recommend leaving `href="#"` in otherwise your anchor tag will behave strangely.

Comment: It works. It is what I want to achieve. Thank you very much. :)